# MySQL: put all values of 1:m into one field?

Tags: mysql, database, lucene, entity-attribute-value

Assume the following possible models:

**Model 1:**

```
TABLE: book
- book_id
- name

TABLE: book_author
- book_author_id
- book_id
- author_id

TABLE: author
- author_id
- name
```

(a book can have 0 or more authors)

**Model 2:**

```
TABLE: book
- book_id
- name

TABLE: book_eav
- book_eav_id
- book_id
- attribute (e.g. "author")
- value (e.g. "Tom Clancy")
```

(a book can have 0 or more authors + information about publisher, number of pages, etc.)

How do I query this in such a way that I get back `book.book_id`, `book.name` + an `authors` field that contains the 0 or more values associated with the book?

I'm trying to do this so I can use the query results as documents in a Lucene index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene supports multiple fields with the same name, meaning that you can actually store multiple fields named "Author" on the same document.

I suggest that you actually do that, and fetch additional data using another statement, for example:

one select for books.
one select for book_id and the author.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the GROUP_CONCAT function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html